# rapidxml - overwriting previous xml_nodes

Tags: rapidxml

I just started using rapidxml. I 1st create an xml file to read from. Worked so fast an easy.

This is what I manual crated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GPS>
    <Path>    
        <Point X="-3684.136" Y="3566.282" Z="285.2893" />
        <Point X="-3681.816" Y="3540.431" Z="283.3658" />
        <Point X="-3687.079" Y="3515.315" Z="282.6284" />
    </Path>
</GPS>
```

I could easy read that with no problems. I then wanted to write it to a new file.
But the problem is that it keeps overwriting previous xml_nodes.

For example,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GPS>
    <Path>
        <Point X="-3687.08" Y="3515.31" Z="282.628"/>
        <Point X="-3687.08" Y="3515.31" Z="282.628"/>
        <Point X="-3687.08" Y="3515.31" Z="282.628"/>
    </Path>
</GPS>
```

This is the code that creates that xml file,

```
int Write(pathStruct *toStore)
{
    xml_document<> doc;

    xml_node<>* decl = doc.allocate_node(node_declaration);
    decl->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("version", "1.0"));
    decl->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("encoding", "UTF-8"));
    doc.append_node(decl);  

    xml_node<> *GPS = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "GPS");
    doc.append_node(GPS);

    cout << "Saving GrindPath " << endl;
    xml_node<> *Path = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "Path");
    GPS->append_node(Path);

    for(int i = 0;i<3;i++) //Temp Static
    {
        xml_node<> *Point = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "Point");
        Path->append_node(Point);

        char x[10];
        FloatToCharA(toStore->X[i], x);
        Point->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("X", x));

        char y[10];
        FloatToCharA(toStore->Y[i], y);
        Point->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("Y", y));

        char z[10];
        FloatToCharA(toStore->Z[i], z);
        Point->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("Z", z));

        //GrindPath->append_node(Point);
        //doc.first_node()->append_node(GrindPath);
        //Point = GrindPath->next_sibling();

        cout << "x:" << toStore->X[i] << "    y:" << toStore->Y[i] << "   z:" << toStore->Z[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << "Done! " << endl;
    std::ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("./toStore.xml");
    myfile << doc;
    return 0;

};
```

My question his how to I stop it from overwriting previous xml_nodes? 
I have attempted many thing but every time its still overwrites previous xml_nodes.
I know it must be simple or I am missing the big picture.

Thank you for your help and time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this will help but this exists in [the documentation](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/manual.html#namespacerapidxml_1two_minute_tutorial):

> One quirk is that nodes and attributes do not own the text of their
>   names and values. This is because normally they only store pointers to
>   the source text. So, when assigning a new name or value to the node,
>   care must be taken to ensure proper lifetime of the string. The
>   easiest way to achieve it is to allocate the string from the
>   xml_document memory pool. In the above example this is not necessary,
>   because we are only assigning character constants. But the code below
>   uses memory_pool::allocate_string() function to allocate node name
>   (which will have the same lifetime as the document), and assigns it to
>   a new node.

I can see in your code that it appears that your char arrays x, y, z are created in scope of your loop and as such do not satisfy the requirements above.