# Rapidxml writing memory error

Tags: rapidxml

I don't undestand why, while BBBString has a different content for every (i,j), on the xml the node "BBB" has always the same value (corresponding to the last couple (i,j) ). The other nodes have the exact content!

```
for (unsigned short int i = 0; i < input1.size(); i++)
    {
        for (unsigned short int j = 0; j < input1[i].size(); j++)
        {
            count = 0;
            max = input1[i][j].size();
            iter = input1[i][j].begin();
            while (count < max)
            {
                rapidxml::xml_node<> * new_node = doc.allocate_node(rapidxml::node_element, "Element");
                new_node->append_node(doc.allocate_node(rapidxml::node_element, "AAA", (*(*iter)).getName().c_str()));

                std::string BBBString = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(input4[i]);
                std::cout << "BBBString = " << BBBString << std::endl;
                new_node->append_node(doc.allocate_node(rapidxml::node_element, "BBB", BBBString.c_str()));
                new_node->append_node(doc.allocate_node(rapidxml::node_element, "CCC", input2[i].getName().c_str()));
                new_node->append_node(doc.allocate_node(rapidxml::node_element, "DDD", input3[j].getName().c_str()));

                other_node->append_node(new_node);
                iter++;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [rapidxml - overwriting previous xml\_nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059679/rapidxml-overwriting-previous-xml-nodes)

Answer (score 0):

Commonly misunderstood aspect of rapidxml. It stores pointers to any strings you pass, rather than duplicating the content. Use allocate_string function, and see this question. [rapidxml - overwriting previous xml_nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059679/rapidxml-overwriting-previous-xml-nodes)